# demonstrate Automatic Hardware Clock Synchronization By the Kernel (11 minute mode) without ntpd

Tags: linux, kernel, time

From the man page of hwclock:

> This mode (we'll call it "11 minute mode") is off until something turns it on.  The ntp daemon xntpd is one thing that turns it  on.   You  can

Ok, I have a virtualbox linux guest without ntp client. There's a 2 minute difference:

```
$ date
Tue Mar 11 18:09:54 MSK 2014
$ hwclock 
Tue 11 Mar 2014 06:08:23 PM MSK  -0.409965 seconds
```

How to enable 11 minute mode?

```
$ adjtimex --print
       status: 64
```

64 means "disabled", right? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man8/adjtimex.8.html

> 64   clock unsynchronized

I thought this will enable the mode

```
$ sudo adjtimex --status 0
```

But it didn't. Status is still 64